# half of a hyperbola

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Only top portion of half my hyperbola is coming in correctly.  The other half is doing something strange:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-3) rectangle (4,3);
      \draw [samples = 50, domain = -0.99:0.99,
      rotate around = {0:(0,0)}, xshift = 0cm, yshift = 0cm]
      plot ({0.69*(1+\x^2)/(1-\x^2)}, {0.72*2*\x/(1-\x^2)});
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You tagged this as pgfplots but not using it. Compare the difference `\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}\addplot [samples = 50, domain = -0.99:0.99]       ({0.69*(1+\x^2)/(1-\x^2)}, {0.72*2*\x/(1-\x^2)});\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Substituting `\x*\x` or `(\x)^2` for `\x^2` fixes your problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-3) rectangle (4,3);
      \draw [samples = 50, domain = -0.99:0.99,
      rotate around = {0:(0,0)}, xshift = 0cm, yshift = 0cm]
      plot ({0.69*(1+\x*\x)/(1-\x*\x)}, {0.72*2*\x/(1-\x*\x)});
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math}
\def\X(#1){COSH(#1)}
\def\Y(#1){SINH(#1)}
\psset{algebraic}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-4)(6,4)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-6,-4)(5.5,3.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psset{linecolor=blue}
    \psparametricplot{-2}{2}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
    \psparametricplot{-2}{2}{-\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case, I don't know if a pstricks answer is really an appropriate alternative.  The question was really about a specific bug in tikz.

Comment: @RyanReich: While the bug is being fixed, we can use it temporarily for emergency solution or permanently.

Comment: Well, the workaround is pretty simple (just use parentheses).  Anyway, I'm not criticizing your answer, just musing on the purpose of adding a package-alternative answer to a question that is not general enough to be answered by an alternative package.  This topic was recently raised [in Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/best-practise-for-answers-which-are-for-the-community-not-the-op-tikz-answer), so it was on my mind.