# Drawing a hyperbola of a certain eccentricity in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is a follow-up question to [half of a hyperbola](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108932/half-of-a-hyperbola).

When constructing a hyperbola in TikZ, how can I specify the eccentricity to be `1.44022`?

Comment: If the equation for the hyperbola is `$x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1$`, then the eccentricity is `$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}/a$`.  Choose `$a$` and `$b$` appropriately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two quantities out of a, b, and e (the eccentricity) determine the hyperbola. You can, for example, define  e(>1) and a(>0), from which you can then derive b. See below.

EDIT: see this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Hyperbolic_functions_and_equations), which explains my parameterisation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\e}{1.44022}   % eccentricity
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{(\a*sqrt((\e)^2-1)} 
    \draw plot[domain=-2:2] ({\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
    \draw plot[domain=-2:2] ({-\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `pgfplots` for these types of problems- you don't have to change your code very much to do it :)

Comment: @Jubobs how are you using hyperbolic trig functions for a hyperbola?

Comment: @dustin trigonometric functions are used for circles and ellipses: `(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1` because of the Pythagorean identity `sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)=1`. Hyperbolic functions are used for Hyperbolae because they satisfy the identity `cosh^2(x)-sinh^2(x)=1`

Comment: @Jubobs `postaction = decorate` doesn't work on this type of tikz picture?  I just tried decorating the hyperbola with arrows at 20 and 60 percent but nothing happened.

Comment: @dustin Your original post does not mention `position=decorate`. You should either edit this question to explain your `position=decorate` problem or post another question dedicated to it.

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\FPset\E{1.440}% 3 digits should be enough
\FPset\A{1}
\FPeval\B{round(A*root(2,E^2-1):3)}

\def\X(#1){\A*COSH(#1)}
\def\Y(#1){\B*SINH(#1)}
\psset{algebraic}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-4)(6,4)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-6,-4)(5.5,3.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psset{linecolor=blue}
    \psparametricplot{-2}{2}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
    \psparametricplot{-2}{2}{-\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```